# preventing double clicks on button with ajax call

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I noticed my users sometimes click the buttons twice, maybe no one told them one click is enough.

What's the best way to prevent the double-click?
I basically hide the button and show a "loading" gif, but that apparently is not enough...

Comment: The problem is that you have double ajax calls or what?

Comment: If I were you, I'd do what epascarello suggested with the double click handler, and also disable the button on first click like Konerak suggested at the beginning of his answer. Should cover quick double clickers and lazy ones too :)

Comment: kindly check my answer once ! hahaha :-D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If they are clicking fast enough to fire the double click event, return false.

```
ondblclick="return false"
```

EDIT: This will not cancel the single click event so problem would still exist.

Comment: Or you could disable the button `onclick` and enable it on success or on error.

Comment: actually this will not work since click will be fired even if this is canceled.

Answer (score 3):

Usually disabling/hiding/replacing the button should work. If they are real fast, try setting a variable to false when your script starts, return if it's true, set it to true after the first click.

```
var alReadyClicked = false;
function click(){
 if (alreadyClicked) 
  return false;
 alreadyClicked = true;
}
```

Don't forget to set it to false when the user can click again.

Answer (score 1):

I just found out the jQuery funcion .one(), that may be useful great for this kind of purpose! great!

Answer (score 1):

The equivalence to JQuery `.one()` may be the `once` option on `AddEventListner` like:

```js
function doSubmit () { /* your code */ }
btn = document.getElementById ('foo');
btn.addEventListener ('click', doSubmit, {once: true});
```

Reference: [javascript - JS equivalent for jQuery one() - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48368112/9758990)

Answer (score 0):

Another example using a flag

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset=utf-8 />
        <title>test dbl click</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button id="btn1">Click Away</button>
        <div id="out"></div>
        <script type="text/javascript">

            function addMessage( msg ){
                document.getElementById("out").innerHTML += (new Date().toTimeString()) + " : " + msg + "<br/><br/>";
            }

            function singleClick(){
                addMessage( "single");
            }

            function addDoubleClickProtection( element, fncToCall ){            
                var isClicked = false;
                var timer = null;
                element.onclick = function(){
                    if(!isClicked){
                        isClicked = true;
                        timer = window.setTimeout( function(){ isClicked = false; }, 200);  
                        return fncToCall();
                    }
                }
            }

            addDoubleClickProtection( document.getElementById("btn1"), singleClick );

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple method by counting the submit button click and with minimum decoration will:

```html
<script>
var click_count = 0;
function submit_once () {
  document.forms.A.elements.cmd.forEach(
    function(e,i,l){e.style.color="#888";}); 
  return (click_count++ > 1); 
}
function reset_count () { 
  document.forms.A.elements.cmd.forEach(
    function(e,i,l){e.style.color="unset";}); 
  click_count = 0; 
}
</script>
<form name="A">
<button type="submit" name="cmd" value="doAdd" 
  onclick="return submit_once();">Do add</button>
<button type="submit" name="cmd" value="doDel" 
  onclick="return submit_once();">Do delete</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a util function `once` which will take `CB` function. And all logic handles `seamlessly`. You don't have to create a `global variable` to `count or update`.

```
function once(cb) {
  let once = false;
  return (...args) => {
    !once && cb(...args);
    once = true;
  };
}
```

**// How to use it.**

// Create/bind function

```
const log = once((data) => {
  console.log(data);
});
```

**// Use it**

```
Promise.resolve("hellowold").then(log).then(log);
```

Above line print only once.