# JS equivalent for jQuery one()

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can someone point me towards a solution for the following? I'm trying to find a JS equivalent for this jQuery code:

```
var formSelector = 'my selector here';
var attribute = 'name';
var formHistory = [];

$(formSelector).one('focusout', function(e) {
    formHistory.push(e['target'].getAttribute(attribute));
});
```

Comment: You can attach the event with [`addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) and then inside it, remove with [`removeEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener).. note that I didn't tested.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's a really simple solution using data attributes.

```js
document.querySelector('#click').addEventListener('click', function(e){
    if(e.currentTarget.dataset.triggered) return;
    e.currentTarget.dataset.triggered = true;
    alert('clicked');
})
```

```html
<button id="click">Click me</button>
```

Comment: Thank you, Jonathan! That's exactly what I was searching for

Comment: This answer doesn't remove the event, hence the other soultions that do are better. just add e.removeEventListener

Answer (score 28):

### Update

In most browsers you can now pass in `once: true` in an options object:

```js
document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click', () => {
  console.log('Hello and goodbye');
}, {
  once: true,
});
```

```html
<button id="btn">Click me</button>
```

---

### Old way

In the eventlistener callback, just destroy the event listener :)
Here's a helper function:

```js
function oneTimeEvent(element, eventType, callback) {
  element.addEventListener(eventType, function(e) {
    e.target.removeEventListener(e.type, arguments.callee);
    return callback(e);
  });
}

var btn = document.querySelector('button');
oneTimeEvent(btn, 'click', function () {
  alert('♫ You clicked me once, but I won\'t let you click me twice, yeah!');
});
```

```html
<button>Click me!</button>
```

Comment: It might be a good idea to declare the function before you bind it to the event, so you can reference the function (instead of `arguments.callee`) when unbinding. Using `callee` is highly discouraged.

Comment: Is there a way to remove `arguments.callee` but retain the ability to use anonymous function names / multiple different functions?

Comment: This answer was given a few years ago. Nowadays you can actually pass `addEventListener` an option object with the property `once: true`.

Answer (score 8):

You could use `once: true` in the `options` parameter passed to [`addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener).

Browser support: Chrome 55+, Firefox 50+, Safari 10, Edge 16, IE not supported.

```js
document.getElementById('foo').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  alert('This will be displayed only once.');
}, { once: true });
```

```html
<button id="foo">Click me</button>
```

Reference:

- [Once Upon an Event Listener](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/10/addeventlistener-once)
- [Can I Use... "once" event listener
  option](https://caniuse.com/#feat=once-event-listener)

Answer (score 2):

Using ES6 and some closure this is a nice way to do it.

```js
const button = document.querySelector('button');

function composeHandler(element, event, handler, ...captureArgs) {
  return function handlerFunc (...args) {
   handler(...args);
    element.removeEventListener(event, handlerFunc, ...captureArgs);
  }
}

function addEventListenerOnce(element, event, handler, ...captureArgs) {
 element.addEventListener(event, composeHandler(element, event, handler, ...captureArgs), ...captureArgs);
}

addEventListenerOnce(button, 'click', (e) => alert('clicked on button ' + e.target.innerText), true)
```

```html
<button>
  Click me once!
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to write your implementation of `one`. Like this:

```
function one(element,eventType,callback,self) {
    var one=function(event) {
        try{
            callback.call(self,event);
        } finally {
            element.removeEventListener(eventType,one);
        }
    }
    element.addEventListener(eventType,one);    
}
```