# How to Append the Href of a Cloned Node (plain JavaScript)

Tags: javascript

When you click on links in the paragraphs, they get cloned & appended to the linkContainer.

I got everything working, except that I want the cloned links that get appended to the linkContainer to show the actual href text (e.g., www.google.com) as the clickable  tag.

I want the displayed link-text in the linkContainer to be the same as the href itself. So e.g., if you click the Google link in the paragraph, it clones & appends the www.google.com to the linkContainer (inside an  tag) as the link text (like < a href="www.google.com">www.google.com < /a>)

I can only find answers for jQuery. I've tried using setAttribute 'href' but I'm not sure if that's what I need for this?

https://jsfiddle.net/dnLd1kLy/2/

```
var linkContainer = document.querySelector('.linkContainer');
var links = document.querySelectorAll('a');

 for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {

  var link = links[i];

  link.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
   event.preventDefault()

  var listItem = document.createElement('li'); // Create a <li> node
  var href = this.cloneNode(true); // Should clone the href www. 

  listItem.appendChild(href); // Append the href to <li></li>

  linkContainer.appendChild(listItem); // append li with the href to container

 });

}
```

Would greatly appreciate some pointers for this, it's driving me nuts! Cheers! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### UPDATE 2

OP requested for the `<a>`nchors to be functioning as by default (i.e. jump to a location designated by the `href` value). The `eventListener` was added to the document originally, so all we need to do is to narrow the `event.currentTarget` to something lower on the DOM. I wrapped the `<p>`aragraphs in a `<section>`, then added the `eventListener` to it. Now if anything that's outside of `section#content` is clicked (e.g. `ul.linkContainer`) will function as normal.

OP wanted to also have the click and copy event happen once for each individual anchor. Normally I would use `removeEventListener()`, but because of how the eventListener is configured, it would inhibit the rest of the anchor's initial behavior on the first click anchor.

Instead, try assigning a flag on each anchor that has been clicked already. If it's clicked again, there should be a condition that would prohibit the copying of the anchor again. See Snippet for latest update.

### UPDATE 1

OP requested that the list also have an anchor, added:

```
listItem.innerHTML = '<a href="'+href+'">'+href+'<\/a>';
```

---

- To get the value of `href`

```
    var href = link.getAttributeNode('href').value;
```

- This value is a String, so instead of `cloneNode`, simply use `innerHTML` or `textContent`

  ```
  listItem.innerHTML = href;
  ```

I changed how the `eventListener` is used on the document instead of individual anchors. Having one eventListener is better than having 2 or more. It's hooked into the `event.target` so now you don't even need to collect every anchor on the document. You only need to execute your function when the click event is fired.

#### SNIPPET

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Untitled Document</title>
  <style>
    .linkContainer {
      width: 300px;
      height: 200px;
      background: #ccc;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <section id="content">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eligendi odio molestiae laboriosam ex enim molestias suscipit, delectus amet impedit, aut ea labore alias deleniti, dignissimos culpa! Blanditiis optio accusamus accusantium!Lorem ipsum dolor
      sit amet, <a href="www.google.com">Google</a> ipisicing elit. Recusandae quisquam obcaecati, perspiciatis velit, <a href="www.twitter.com">Twitter</a> illo facere dolor officia, ab omnis commodi accusamus deleniti ea, maiores unde quae in accusantium
      eum possimus.</p>

    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sint, facere dignissimos corporis laboriosam sequi nobis facilis. Quam, illum, deleniti. Excepturi odit suscipit ratione distinctio. Commodi, animi dolor dolore <a href="www.youtube.com">Youtube</a> ius.Lorem
      ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Architecto deleniti praesentium libero et corporis nam eveniet odit sed. Ducimus perferendis esse atque libero nam amet sed? Consequatur aspernatur consectetur, quos!</p>
  </section>

  <ul class="linkBox">


  </ul>

  <script>
    var linkContainer = document.querySelector('.linkBox');
    var txt = document.getElementById('content');

    txt.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
      
      if (event.target != event.currentTarget) {
        var link = event.target;
        
        // So the next time around, if the link was already clicked, the data-fired attribute would meet the conditional's requirement. That in turn will kick you out of the function before the even.preventDefault() so now it's in every aspect a normal anchor again.
        if (link.dataset.fired) { return };
        event.preventDefault();
        
        // Set a data-* attribute called data-fired
        link.dataset.fired = true;
        event.stopPropagation();
      }

      
   
      var listItem = document.createElement("li");
      // Create a <li> node

      var href = link.getAttributeNode('href').value;
      // Should be the actual href www. 
      console.log(href);
      listItem.innerHTML = '<a href="' + href + '">' + href + '<\/a>';
      // Append the href to <li></li>
      linkContainer.appendChild(listItem);
      // append li with the href to container

    }, false);
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

#### REFERENCE

https://stackoverflow.com/a/36312449/2813224

Comment: Thanks a lot, it's great, except one problem, the appended link needs to be inside a clickable <a> tag, like it is in the Fiddle I provided. So I need to add something like createElement("a") or...? Not sure how to fit it in..

Comment: Awesome, that's exactly it! I like the hook on event.target too, I can see why my previous code was a bit dirty. One more question, now when the links are in the container.. is there some way to stop them from still getting targeted by the function? If you click on them after they're in the container, they just start copying each other. It would be awesome if they just worked like regular links now..  Can we limit the amount of times you can click on the same, or just cancel the function after a link is added? If you get me...

Comment: That makes the effort worth it, sir.  What makes this specific code really nice is the use of `event.target`. I got a lot from this [article](https://www.kirupa.com/html5/handling_events_for_many_elements.htm)

Answer (score 4):

add

```
href.text = this.href
```

after the href var setting

https://jsfiddle.net/dnLd1kLy/3/

Comment: I was thinking `href.innerHTML = href.href;` but same difference.