# Vanilla JS equivalent to jQuery $.once()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, drupal

Working on a Drupal 9 site and trying to add some custom JS code to a page.

```
Drupal.behaviors.syfyGlobalHideMenu = {
  attach: function (context, settings) {
    $('.nav-flyout', context).once('remove-modals', function () {
      $(document).keyup(function (e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 27) {
          $('.nav-flyout', context).removeClass('js-flyout-active');
        }
      });
    });
  }
};
```

Wondering if there's a vanilla JS equivalent to the jQuery .once functionality above?
Currently Drupal attaches the event listener multiple times and I am trying to avoid that as I only want to attach the event listener once but have it remain attached and run every time the event is invoked.

```
let intervalID = null;
const search = document.querySelector(".call-us-table input#edit-search");

search.addEventListener("keydown", event => {
  form.setAttribute("onsubmit", "return false");
  clearInterval(intervalID);
});
search.addEventListener("keyup", event => {
  intervalID = setInterval(submitForm, 2000);
});
```

Comment: this is a similar issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36312249/js-equivalent-for-jquery-one/36312449

Comment: I saw that but it seems there's a difference between .once and .one. I don't want the event listener called only once, I want it attached to the element only once but can still be continually called. Drupal is attaching the event listener multiple times.

Comment: You can just set an attribute in the behavior object to keep track of if the event listener has been attached... hmm, maybe I need to give an example. Are you planning to keep using jquery for the selectors but just not use jquery.once?

Comment: hmm, why are you adding the event listener from within a selector? It seems unnecessary to me, unless the '.nav-flyout' is not included on initial page load and is loaded via ajax.

Answer (score 2):

Since 9.2, Drupal has had the `core/once` library, just for this purpose.

To use it, you add dependencies to your libraries.yml, as follows:

```
my_search:
  version: 1.x
  js:
    js/my_search.js: {}
  dependencies:
    - core/drupal
    - core/once
```

Then in `my_search.js`:

```
(function (Drupal, once) {
 Drupal.behaviors.my_search = {
   attach (context) {
     once('my_search', '.call-us-table input#edit-search', context).forEach((search) => {
       search.addEventListener('keydown', () => {
         ...
       });
       search.addEventListener('keyup', () => {
         ...
       });
     });
   }
 }
})(Drupal, once);
```

Answer (score 0):

Jquery once adds an html attribute to check if is the first time to run.

```
function vanillaOnce() {
  if (!document.body.getAttribute('data-once')) {
    document.body.setAttribute('data-once', 'true');
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}

if (vanillaOnce) {
  console.log('runs only once');
}
```

Comment: Thanks! so how would I implement that code to fit into the "keydown" and "keyup" event listeners I added to the end of my above question? To make sure those event listeners continue to fire off but only get attached to the `search` element once.

Comment: The code posted in this answer wont always work with drupal behaviors as sometimes you want to do something on something that is returned by ajax, which this would stop.

Comment: JQuery once adds an attribute (class) to he element being selected, not the whole document.