# how to display 1 data without looping using insertAdjacentHTML

Tags: javascript, html, insertadjacenthtml

I'm having a problem. why is the **insertAdjacentHTML("afterend")** output looping?, i want to display 1 only, not repeated.

```js
var btn = document.getElementById("btnClick");
btn.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var string= "";
    string += '<p>FINISH</p>';
    document.querySelector(".test").insertAdjacentHTML("afterend", string);
});
```

```html
<button id="btnClick">CLICK</button>
<div class="test"></div>
```

Comment: I can only see one FINISH in the jsfiddle you've provided. Can you clarify your problem?

Comment: try to click again and again the button, if you click the button continuously it will loop.

Comment: You want to disable the click listener once it fired, by passing an extra parameter, `{ once: true }`, as seen here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36312249/js-equivalent-for-jquery-one

Comment: You can add a variable (such as `flag`), before you add the element check if `flag` is set, if it is not set, add the element and set `flag` to true, else do nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want only one adjacent HTML added, you need to disable the `onclick` listener (or replace/remove existing HTML with the new one). You can make a `click` listener to fire once by adding an extra parameter when setting it, `{ once: true }`, like below:

```js
var btn = document.getElementById("btnClick");
btn.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var string= "";
    string += '<p>FINISH</p>';
    document.querySelector(".test").insertAdjacentHTML("afterend", string);
}, { once: true });
```

```html
<button id="btnClick">CLICK</button>
<div class="test"></div>
```

For replacing the element you've added, you can use `nextElementSibling` to replace it. I'm assuming there is nothing after `.test` element initially, you might want to test that first so you don't accidentally remove elements you don't want to:

```js
var btn = document.getElementById("btnClick");
btn.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var string= "";
    string += '<p>FINISH</p>';
    document.querySelector(".test").nextElementSibling.remove();
    document.querySelector(".test").insertAdjacentHTML("afterend", string);
});
```

```html
<button id="btnClick">CLICK</button>
<div class="test"></div>
```

Comment: wow this is great using "nextElementSibling" it's really working and to my liking