Trouble with a single ON/OFF type button in Javascript
I'll preface this by saying that I'm trying to learn JS.
I'm currently trying to make a button that hides GIFs (or other moving images) when clicked, then changes to a "show GIFs" button until clicked again.
So the button needs to do 2 things:

Hide/show all images of a certain class, choosing correctly based on their current display status
Switch which button it is on use

I have figured out the first part on its own, but I can't figure out the second effectively.
I'm also not sure how to approach the button changing? I was thinking about having 2 buttons on the page and using relative + absolute positioning to have the buttons overlay each other, and just switch which class of button is visible tied to their respective functions, but if there's a better way to do that by all means correct me.
I did see a solution on here using an input as a button for ease of switching, but I've also read that its bad practice to use an input when you could use a button? If thats outdated though just let me know.
Here's the JS that successfully hid images on click:
var x = document.getElementsByClassName('flash');
function hide() {
  for(var i=0; i<x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.display = 'none';
    }
}
function show() {
  for(var i=0; i<x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.display = 'block';
    }
}

Here's where I hit a wall trying to combine things:
var imagesHidden = false;
var myBtn = document.getElementById("gifTog");
myBtn.onclick = function togGIF(){
      var images = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("flash"));
      if(imagesHidden){
            imagesHidden = false;
            images.forEach(function(img){
               img.style.display = "block";
            });
            myBtn.Element.className = "hide";
      } else {
            imagesHidden = true;
            images.forEach(function(img){
               img.style.display = "none";
            });
            myBtn.Element.className = "show";
      }
};

& here's the page I'm testing it: https://ooops.lol/testing/test
Honestly I was half expecting it not to work because I am horrible at parsing JS, and this is the most complicated function I've tried to tackle.
I asked for help elsewhere and that is where the second chunk of code came from, I would not be surprised if I just made a mistake changing some things or explained my goal poorly.
Any help is appreciated!

https://stackoverflow.com/a/36312421/2569323 Do you get the idea here?

I do get the concept, I'd have to check that it'd work multiple times if the element stops being displayed then comes back I think for this case? But bookmarking for shenanigans either way lol

In step #2 you don't reuse the code from step #1. A big no no. Try to organize into functions.
I also added a generic function to toggle button text between 2 states.
It makes sense to change state of variable imagesHidden inside the respective show and hide functions.


var imagesHidden = false;
var x = document.querySelectorAll('.flash');
var myBtn = document.getElementById("gifTog");

function hide() {
  imagesHidden = true
  for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.display = 'none';
  }
  console.log ("gifs are now hidden")
}

function show() {
  imagesHidden = false
  var x = document.querySelectorAll('.flash');
  for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.display = 'block';
  }
  console.log ("gifs are now shown")
}

function alternateButtonText(btn) {
  var current = btn.innerText
  btn.innerText = btn.getAttribute("data-alt-text")
  btn.setAttribute("data-alt-text", current)
}

myBtn.onclick = function togGIF() {
  alternateButtonText(myBtn)
  if (imagesHidden) {
    show()
  } else {
    hide()
  }
};
<button id="gifTog" data-alt-text="show GIFs">hide GIFs</button>




First off, this makes significantly more sense, thank you so much! I think I mostly get myself confused in JS when trying to figure out how to layer things, so this will go a long way.
I fear however that the button works when running here, but not when I try to put it on the test page. I'm getting "Uncaught TypeError: myBtn is null" on the log.

if myBtn is null, then the variable exists and is not undefined. so maybe when you var myBtn = document.getElementById("gifTog"); the gifTog button doesn't exist yet? (The page is rendered from top to bottom)

Okay, I see what you mean. I put that JS in its own file and moved its HTML tags below the button and now it mostly works, but for some reason only "show" changes the element (which doesn't do anything of course, but I can see "display=block" being added to the HTML when I press it the second time).
This is leaps and bounds closer than I was before so no worries if you run out of steam lol, I do have a sense of what I'm looking at now.

update: it was a syntax issue, its working flawlessly now! thank you again so much
