# How to prevent two identical Boostrap dialog from opening by user double clicking the button?

Tags: jquery, ajax, bootstrap-modal, double-click

In case the ajax take a while to load the dialog and user double clicking the button, two identical dialog will popup on the screen. I want to prevent it from happening.

```
$("#ShowUpCallTag").on('click', function (e) {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/Ship/CallTags/Dialog/' + $(e.target).data('calltagid'),
            type: 'get',
            datatype: 'json'
        }).done(function (data) {
            var dialog = main.ship.calltags.dialog.buildDialog(data);
            dialog.open();
        });
    });
```

Comment: Check this solution. http://stackoverflow.com/a/4491717/3585278

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the problem in your code is that you don't know if a dialog is opened or not. What I would do :

1. Create a variable in the same scope than your jQuery call, for example : `var dialogOpened = false`
2. In your click handler function, do the ajax call only if `dialogOpened === false`
3. In your `done(function (data) {})` callback, set `dialogOpened` to true and listen for Bootstrap generated event to know when the modal is closed by the user (see [Bootstrap Modal Events](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-events))
4. When the modal is closed, set back `dialogOpened`to false.
5. What I consider to be a good practice also : if the element on which you bind the click is a button, you can disable it just after the user has clicked on it.

Answer (score 0):

```
           var isModelDialogOpen = false;
           $("#ShowUpCallTag").on('click', function (e) {
             if (isModelDialogOpen == false) {
                isModelDialogOpen = true;

                //Popup call tag dialog.
                $.ajax({
                  url: '/Ship/CallTags/Dialog/' + $(e.target).data('calltagid'),
                  type: 'get',
                  datatype: 'json'
                    .done(function (data) {
                       var dialog = main.ship.calltags.dialog.buildDialog(data);
                       dialog.open();
                    })
                    .always(function (data) {

                        isModelDialogOpen = false;
                    });
            }
        });
```

Comment: This doesn't look like valid JavaScript. Which object is `.done` supposed to be called on?